# ggplot2: two time series with different and irregular date intervals in a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the ggplot2 package, I would like to obtain a plot that contains two time series that have data points on different dates.

For instance, one data frame looks like:

```
date1, value1  
2010-01-05, 2921.74  
2010-01-08, 2703.89  
2010-01-14, 3594.21  
2010-01-20, 3659.22
```

The other data frame looks like

```
date2, value2  
2010-01-01, 285.85  
2010-01-02, 229.20  
2010-01-05, 333.91  
2010-01-06, 338.27  
2010-01-07, 272.85  
2010-01-08, 249.04  
2010-01-09, 240.07  
2010-01-10, 255.06  
2010-01-11, 275.42  
2010-01-12, 252.39
```

I would like to plot these two time series in one and the same plot, with date on the X axis and value on the Y axis. It's fairly easy with {base} plot, but I'd like to do it with ggplot.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use two `geom_point`'s with different `data` arguments:

```
ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + geom_point(data = df1) + geom_point(data = df2)
```

This assumes that your datasets are called `df1` and `df2`, and that they have the same column names.

Even easier would be to combine the two datasets, and add an identifying column:

```
df1$id = "one"
df2$id = "two"
df = rbind(df1, df2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value, color = id)) + geom_point()
```

This last solution is more inline with the philosophy of `ggplot2`. Note that this approach works in a similar fashion for `geom_line`.

An example:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = depth, color = cut)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: that is, after setting column names of both data.frames to `date` and `value` (as opposed to date1 and date2 ..), of course.

Comment: @Arun the second way, adding together the datasets and using `color = id` is a better solution still I think.

Comment: To begin with, I'd suggest the 2nd way as it gives a more concrete rule and hides the power of adding layers on top one by one. But once you get to know the workings of ggplot2, I guess both are more or less the same, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Arun the second I think is much more in the spirit of how `ggplot2` is meant to work. The datasets aren't really different, it's just two different realizations of the same data. This makes the second example much more relevant. The first one is more of an old-skool approach where not data visualization, but drawing lines is the focus.